# linear algebra matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following matrix $A$, find an invertible matrix $U$ so that $UA$ is equal to the reduced row-echelon form of $A$:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Hint: do elementary column operations to $A$ and $I$ at the same time.

Comment: OP wants it on the left

Comment: @DougM: operating on rows amounts to *pre*-multiplying by an elementary operation matrix.

Comment: oh, so rows are on the left, oops I need to revisit this stuff

Answer (score 1):

- Swap rows $1$ and $3$, i.e. pre-multiply  by the matrix $\;U_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$. You get
  $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1&-2\\0&2&2&2\\0&3&3&3\end{bmatrix}. $$
- Multiply the (new) second row by $1/2$,  i.e. multiply  by the matrix $\;U_2=\smash{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\frac12&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}$ to get
  $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1&-2\\0&1&1&1\\0&3&3&3\end{bmatrix}. $$
- $R_3\leftarrow R_3-3R_2$, i.e. multiply on the left by $\;U_3=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&-3&1\end{bmatrix}$ to get
  $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1&-2\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}. $
- Substract $R_2$ from $R_1$, i.e. multiply on the left by $\;U_4=\smash[b]{\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}$ to get the reduced row echelon form:
  $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2&-3\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.\qquad\qquad  $$
  In all you have multiplied by
  $$U=U_4U_3U_2U_1.$$

Comment: Is $U_3$ correct?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, wrong copy-paste. I'll fix within a second.